# How can I check if GDI is hardware-accelerated?

Tags: windows, gdi

[This documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/blob/staging/windows-driver-docs-pr/display/gdi-hardware-acceleration.md) mentions that the driver should set DXGKDDI_INTERFACE_VERSION to Windows 7 or above to indicate that it supports the hardware-acceleration of GDI. But how do I check that the value is indeed that ? Is it a reg key ?

Comment: [No](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/driverentry-of-display-miniport-driver#remarks)

Comment: @HansPassant not sure what you mean...

Comment: 1. Hardware acceleration is not a boolean.  Every device has some operations which are accelerated and some which are not.  2. The documentation is very misleading, using generic language but actually describing one very specific form of acceleration.  GDI drivers have used hardware acceleration long before Windows 7.